# Disable Check In / Check Out prompt Sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, check-in

I was just wondering if it is possible to dissable the check in / check out prompts when interacting with document libraries in Sharepoint 2010.  I am writing an application and it is quite frustrating to constantly have to check in / check out documents if you want to interact with them

Is it possible to automatically check in / check out documents without user input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Tell me first are you trying to do this programatically ?

If yes, then you have to write a custom code to disable required checkout option for the documents in that document library.

If you don't want to disable that setting then you have to write custom coding for the Programtically check in / checkout of file in document library

See this example.

http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2010/09/05/programmatically-check-incheck-out-documents-in-sharepoint-2010/

hope this helps